# My apps will not install on device when downloaded from the Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I am unable to install my app onto a device even when it is downloaded from the Android Market. How can this be possible? If it were signed incorrectly wouldn't the market not accept it? I have tried to install it by isolating various activities but none seem to work even when I reduce it to a simple hello world application. The app has a tab view, two being webviews [one includes a reload button] and one tab that allows a user to send an email to a submission page. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am missing?

Thank you all very much in advance.

EDIT:

It's being downloaded on the LG Ally running 2.2.2 and my app runs fine on an 2.2 emulator. It is compiled with a min level of 4. Here is my AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name=".BrotipsTabs"
              android:label="Brotips">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TabWidget"
          android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".Random"
          android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".Sub"
          android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".BrotipsTabs" android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
      </activity>
<meta-data android:name="com.mobclix.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="<Key>"/>
<activity android:name="com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixBrowserActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> <uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

By not working I mean it refuses to install and claims it never did while an icon remains on the phone.

Comment: What is the make and model of your device?  What version of Android is it running?  What version of Android is your app?  What version was it compiled as?  What's in your AndroidManifest file?  In what way does it not work?

Comment: It also would be nice to see logs for the installation failure.

Comment: It's being downloaded on the LG Ally running 2.2.2 and my app runs fine on an 2.2 emulator. It is compiled with a min level of 4.

Comment: I always (well almost always) load the exported app directly to my phone over usb before I upload it to the Android Market using the adb command adb install ~/myapp.apk. Of course, you must remove the old app from the phone and set applications on the phone to allow non market applications. If you load a debug version onto your phone, it will BLOCK the release version from loading as the signatures will not match.

Comment: This ancient question never had enough information to make it answerable; now the community daemon has churned it back up.  It should be closed before it wastes any more readers time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any previous versions of your app installed on your phone? If you have an apk that is signed with the debug signature (which eclipse uses when you push run) and try to install it from the market which is signed with an actual signature then it will fail due to the two signatures being different. The message that it shows you is different on different devices I've found. If you have any previous versions of your app installed you should uninstall them and try to install from the market again. You should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I have uninstalled in between every test. Is there other issue it might be?

Comment: Two questions, does it install and run if you do it from adb or eclipse? and do you know if install fails for everyone from the market? or do you only know for sure that it fails for you?

Comment: I cannot be sure that it installs from eclipse because I do not have access to a device. I have checked with multiple downloaders and they all have the same issue. I found the following in my error log however: [randomtab.xml: android.webkit.WebView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup] and [com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView failed to instantiate] and [No command output when running: 'am start -n com.soma.brotips/com.soma.brotips.BrotipsTabs -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554] could these be fatal issues?

Comment: Probably, sounds like mobclix is using a WebView and is trying to add another view to it, as though it is actually a view group. One way to test would be to take out the mobclix module and see if it works without.